# ClearML SSH port forwarding fileserver not available in WEB Ui

Tags: devops, local, portforwarding, trains, clearml

Trying to use clearml-server on own Ubuntu 18.04.5 with SSH Port Forwarding and not beeing able to see my debug samples.

My setup:

- ClearML server on hostA
- SSH Tunnel connections to access Web App from working machine via localhost:18080
- Web App: `ssh -N -L 18081:127.0.0.1:8081 user@hostA`
- Fileserver: `ssh -N -L 18081:127.0.0.1:8081 user@hostA`

In Web App under Task->Results->Debug Samples the Images are still refrenced by localhost:8081

Where can I set the fileserver URL to be localhost:18081 in Web App?
I tried ~/clearml.conf, but this did not work ( I think it is for my python script ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm a member of the ClearML team (formerly Trains)

In ClearML, debug images' URL is registered once they are uploaded to the fileserver. The WebApp doesn't actually decide on the URL for each debug image, but rather obtains it for each debug image from the server. This allows you to potentially upload debug images to a variety of storage targets, ClearML File Server simply being the most convenient, built-in option.

So, the WebApp will always look for `localhost:8008` for debug images that have already been uploaded to the fileserver and contain `localhost:8080` in their URL.
A possible solution is to simply add another tunnel in the form of `ssh -N -L 8081:127.0.0.1:8081 user@hostA`.

For future experiments, you can choose to keep using `8081` (and keep using this new tunnel), or to change the default fileserver URL in `clearml.conf` to point to port `localhost:18081`, assuming you're running your experiments from the same machine where the tunnel to `18081` exists.

Comment: thanks. 
I understand. your suggested port forwarding works.